# vim backup files

Tags: vim, backup

Ok, I'm embarrassed to admit I'm having trouble with backup files in Vim. Here's what's in my .vimrc:

```
set backup
set backupdir=~/backup/
set dir=~/backup/
```

And it's at the very bottom of the file. At the moment no .bak or .swp files are ever generated. I've verified that the directory exists. anyone have any ideas that I can pursue on this?

thanks...

Comment: Examine the output of `:verbose set backup? backupcopy? backupskip?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I'd check if the init gets to that point. E.g. after starting `vim`, I'd issue some of these:

```
:set backup?
:set backupdir?
:set dir?
```

If any of the above doesn't correspond to your settings then some error(s) should be in your `.vimrc`, and the init exits on that error.

Of course you can check if the `~/backup` dir has write access...

HTH